# How to find the row number of max data and set to 0

Tags: excel, vba

I use the vba to find the max number and the related row for a list. After finding the max number, the max number will be set to zero.

```
a   0.695115507
b   0.980003238
c   0.243931353
d   0.533873081
e   0.106369674
f   0.999414563
g   0.676175892
h   0.015703917
i   0.575183809
j   0.100052238
k   0.103022635
l   0.798884392
m   0.284480274
n   0.045649171
o   0.295772851
p   0.382010698
q   0.300970495
r   0.948571086

Name for max    Max number  
#VALUE!        0.999414563
```

code:

```
For k = 25 To 42
Range("D45").Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D" & 25 & ":" & "D" & 42))

WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D" & 25 & ":" & "D" & 42)).Value = 0
end k
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try this also:

```
MaxNo = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D25:D42"))
Rmax = WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxNo, Range("D25:D42"), 0)
Cells(Rmax, 1).Value = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, will do the job done.

```
Sub test()

Dim MaxVal As Single
Dim MaxValRow As Integer

MaxVal = CDec(Cells(1, 1).Value)

For k = 1 To 18
    If MaxVal < CDec(Cells(k + 1, 1).Value) Then
        MaxVal = CDec(Cells(k + 1, 1))
        MaxValRow = k + 1
    End If
Next k

Cells(MaxValRow, 1).Value = 0

End Sub
```